# DotNetZip - Adding Folders

Tags: c#, compression, dotnetzip

i imagine this is very simple but i can find nothing in the DotNetZip examples or documentation to help me. I need to add a folder to a zip that contains both folders and files, i need to maintain the folders rather than only zipping their files but using the following it always strips away the folders:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@TempLoc);
                    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@TempLoc);
                    zip.AddFiles(files, "Traces");

                    foreach (string fol in folders)
                    {
                        zip.AddDirectory(fol, "Traces");
                    }

                    zip.Comment = "These traces were gathered " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                    zip.Save(arcTraceLoc + userName.Text + "-Logs.zip");
                }
```

I'm using the loop as i could not find a function for folders similar to 'AddFiles' in DotNetZip.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this work? `zip.AddDirectory(fol, Path.Combine("Traces", fol));`

Comment: That 'worked' but put the full path to the folder under the same directory as 'Traces', i need the exact data present in 'fol' to go into the specified 'Traces' directory within the zip.

Comment: `zip.AddDirectory(fol, Path.Combine("Traces", new DirectoryInfo(fol).Name));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
  bool recurseDirectories = true;
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddSelectedFiles("*", @TempLoc, string.Empty, recurseDirectories);
    zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but unfortunately this throws an exception:

"System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs"

Not the most helpful error...i guess that we're missing some parameters maybe?

Comment: That's not helpful at all...are you sure there's not more to the exception that you're just not seeing?

Comment: Fiddled a little more and found you have to add a 'string.empty' to the 3rd Arg on AddSelectedFiles(), works a treat now :)

Cheers.

Comment: In any typical case, `""` and `string.Empty` are the same. Which you use is mainly a stylistic choice, and I find it highly unlikely that this is what really fixed your problem. I edited my answer to include `""` and you posted about `string.Empty` fixing it at about the same time I think, so maybe you just missed it.